# How can I get an element before doing a map of it?

Tags: reactjs

So the title isn't very clear but basically I'm trying to get the `city` properties of this element :
[image]

In order to use it in the code (under `icon` I'd like to define `city={weather.city.name}` to pass it to the `WeatherCard` element) :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import WeatherCard from './WeatherCard'

const WeatherList = ({weathers}) => {
    console.log("weathers:")
    console.log(weathers)
    return (
        <Row>
           {weathers.list.map(({dt, main, weather}) => (
                <Col key={dt}>
                    <WeatherCard 
                    temp_max={main.temp_max} 
                    temp_min={main.temp_min} 
                    dt={dt * 1000} 
                    main={weather[0].main} 
                    icon={weather[0].icon}
                  />
                </Col>
            ))} 
        </Row>
    )
}

export default WeatherList;
```

and my `WeatherCard.js` is like this :

```
const WeatherCard = ({dt, temp_min, temp_max, main, icon, city  }) => {
  const WeatherIcon = styled.div`color: whitesmoke;`;
  console.log("city:" + city)
  const refresh = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  let weatherIcon = null;
  


  // create a date object with Date class constructor
  const date = new Date(dt);
  return (
    <div className="main">
        <Card style={{width: '18rem'}}>
        <Card.Img
            variant="top"
            // get the src from example url and pass the icon prop for icon code
            src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}@2x.png`}
        />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{main}</Card.Title>
            {/*  datetime is received in milliseconds, let's turn into local date time */}
            <p>
            {date.toLocaleDateString()} - {date.toLocaleTimeString()}
            </p>
            {/* minimum temperature */}
            <p>Min: {temp_min}</p>
            {/* maximum temperature */}
            <p>Max: {temp_max}</p>
        </Card.Body>
        </Card>        
    </div>  
  );
};

export default WeatherCard;
```

I can't figure out how I should do that, can you put me on the right way ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just use `city={weathers.city.name}`?

Comment: @DhilipH because I didn't think about it :'(

Comment: No worries. Take care :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `city={weathers.city.name}` with `s` in `weather`

```
<WeatherCard
  temp_max={main.temp_max}
  temp_min={main.temp_min}
  dt={dt * 1000}
  main={weather[0].main}
  icon={weather[0].icon}
  city={weathers.city.name}
/>;
```